# Exponential decay fit in r

Tags: r, statistics, model-fitting, function-fitting

I would like to fit an exponential decay function in R to the following data:

```
data <- structure(list(x = 0:38, y = c(0.991744340878828, 0.512512332368168, 
0.41102449265681, 0.356621905557202, 0.320851602373477, 0.29499198506227, 
0.275037747162642, 0.25938850981822, 0.245263623938863, 0.233655093612007, 
0.224041426946405, 0.214152907133301, 0.207475138903635, 0.203270738895484, 
0.194942528735632, 0.188107106969046, 0.180926819430008, 0.177028560207711, 
0.172595416846822, 0.166729221891201, 0.163502461048814, 0.159286528409165, 
0.156110097827889, 0.152655498715612, 0.148684858095915, 0.14733605355542, 
0.144691873223729, 0.143118852619617, 0.139542186417186, 0.137730138713745, 
0.134353615271572, 0.132197800438632, 0.128369567159113, 0.124971834736476, 
0.120027536018095, 0.117678812415655, 0.115720611113327, 0.112491329844252, 
0.109219168085624)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-39L), .Names = c("x", "y"))
```

I've tried fitting with nls but the generated curve is not close to the actual data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uu2l.png)

It would be very helpful if anyone could explain how to work with such nonlinear data and find a function of best fit.

Comment: Can you also post the function you are using for the exponential decay? The one you are passing in nls.

Comment: I'm currently passing y ~ a * exp(-b * x)

Comment: Is there a theoretical reason to expect the data to follow a decaying exponential or are you just eyeballing it?

Comment: No reason, just eyeballing it.

Comment: @Scratch What do you need the fit for? Parameter values? Predictions?

Comment: Its for predictions, the data is essentially a survival rate that I am trying to model.

Comment: @Scatch Your last comment is self-contradicting. Do you want to predict `y` or are you interested in the decay constant?

Comment: @Roland How is that contradicting? If you can model the decay accurately, you are predicting 'y'.

Comment: @Scratch No, if you are interested in an underlying parameter you are doing inference. If you want to predict y values, your approach usually is different (stronger focus on validation/cross-validation, other models could be used).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `y ~ .lin / (b + x^c)`.  Note that when using `"plinear"` one omits the `.lin` linear parameter when specifying the formula to `nls` and also omits a starting value for it.

Also note that the `.lin` and `b` parameters are approximately 1 at the optimum so we could also try the one parameter model `y ~ 1 / (1 + x^c)`.  This is the form of a one-parameter log-logistic survival curve. The AIC for this one parameter model is worse than for the 3 parameter model (compare `AIC(fm1)` and `AIC(fm3)`) but the one parameter model might still be preferable due to its parsimony and the fact that the fit is visually indistinguishable from the 3 parameter model.

```
opar <- par(mfcol = 2:1, mar = c(3, 3, 3, 1), family = "mono")

# data = data.frame with x & y col names; fm = model fit; main = string shown above plot
Plot <- function(data, fm, main) {
  plot(y ~ x, data, pch = 20)
  lines(fitted(fm) ~ x, data, col = "red")
  legend("topright", bty = "n", cex = 0.7, legend = capture.output(fm))
  title(main = paste(main, "- AIC:", round(AIC(fm), 2)))
}  

# 3 parameter model
fo3 <- y ~ 1/(b + x^c) # omit .lin parameter; plinear will add it automatically
fm3 <- nls(fo3, data = data, start = list(b = 1, c = 1), alg = "plinear")
Plot(data, fm3, "3 parameters")

# one parameter model
fo1 <- y ~ 1 / (1 + x^c)
fm1 <- nls(fo1, data, start = list(c = 1))
Plot(data, fm1, "1 parameter")

par(read.only = opar)
```

[image: screenshot]

### AIC

Adding the solutions in the other answers we can compare the AIC values.  We have labelled each solution by the number of parameters it uses (the degrees of freedom would be one greater than that) and have reworked the log-log solution to use `nls` instead of `lm` and have a LHS of y since one cannot compare the AIC values of models having different left hand sides or using different optimization routines since the log likelihood constants used could differ.

```
fo2 <- y ~ exp(a + b * log(x+1))
fm2 <- nls(fo2, data, start = list(a = 1, b = 1))

fo4 <- y ~ SSbiexp(x, A1, lrc1, A2, lrc2)
fm4 <- nls(fo4, data)

aic <- AIC(fm1, fm2, fm3, fm4)
aic[order(aic$AIC), ]
```

giving from best AIC (i.e. fm3) to worst AIC (i.e. fm2):

```
    df     AIC
fm3  4 -329.35
fm1  2 -307.69
fm4  5 -215.96
fm2  3 -167.33
```

Answer (score 1):

A biexponential model would fit much better, though still not perfect. This would indicate that you might have two simultaneous decay processes.

```
fit <- nls(y ~ SSbiexp(x, A1, lrc1, A2, lrc2), data = data)
#A1*exp(-exp(lrc1)*x)+A2*exp(-exp(lrc2)*x)

plot(y ~x, data = data)
curve(predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x)), add = TRUE)
```

[image: resulting plot]

If the measurement error depends on magnitude, you could consider using it for weighting.

However, you should consider carefully what kind of model you'd expect from your domain knowledge. Just selecting a non-linear model empirically is usually not a good idea. A non-parametric fit might be a better option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do admit I selected the function empirically. So, how would you go about finding the underlying function that best explains the relationship in the data?

Comment: I would first consider what I know about my data and look into literature. If there is nothing to be found in the literature, I would look if I could derive a differential equation myself and try to solve it.

Comment: In particular, there is a rich body of literature regarding survival analysis (not my area of expertise).

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- structure(list(x = 0:38, y = c(0.991744340878828, 0.512512332368168, 
0.41102449265681, 0.356621905557202, 0.320851602373477, 0.29499198506227, 
0.275037747162642, 0.25938850981822, 0.245263623938863, 0.233655093612007, 
0.224041426946405, 0.214152907133301, 0.207475138903635, 0.203270738895484, 
0.194942528735632, 0.188107106969046, 0.180926819430008, 0.177028560207711, 
0.172595416846822, 0.166729221891201, 0.163502461048814, 0.159286528409165, 
0.156110097827889, 0.152655498715612, 0.148684858095915, 0.14733605355542, 
0.144691873223729, 0.143118852619617, 0.139542186417186, 0.137730138713745, 
0.134353615271572, 0.132197800438632, 0.128369567159113, 0.124971834736476, 
0.120027536018095, 0.117678812415655, 0.115720611113327, 0.112491329844252, 
0.109219168085624)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-39L), .Names = c("x", "y"))

# Do this because the log of 0 is not possible to calculate
data$x = data$x +1

fit = lm(log(y) ~ log(x), data = data)
plot(data$x, data$y)
lines(data$x, data$x ^ fit$coefficients[2], col = "red")
```

This did a lot better than using the nls forumla. And when plotting the fit seems to do fairly well.

Comment: You should be mindful of the implications of performing a log transform then a linear fit, though ([e.g.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/254706/69709)).

Comment: Thanks for that! When I try your approach though, the function is still not fitted well, I am guessing it requires a coefficient as a multiple to data$x ^ fit$coefficients[2]. Would you know how to fit that?

Comment: What are you expecting it to look like? It is possible that your data is not perfectly exponential.

Comment: Not expecting anything in particular, however considering how smooth the decay curve looks like from my data, I was hoping I could find a model that fits rather accurately, but I guess I'm being too optimistic

Comment: Take a look at the log log graph and if it is was perfectly exponential it would be a perfect line.